# Why I cannot use Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to use ChromeDrive but getting error or not excuted well.

My simple java code for testing was:

```
@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "lib\\chromedriver.exe");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
  Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
  WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
  searchBox.submit();
  Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
  driver.quit();
}
```

Following this tutorial:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

[image]

Comment: What error so you see?

Comment: Only loading of the image above, and after few seconds, the terminal seems reloading.Nothing happens after that. I just need to close it manually.

I have code for Firefox Driver and had no issue.

Comment: are you using windows machine?

Comment: Hi @Mona, yes using Windows 10 OS
I remember before, when I was using Windows 7, I don't encountered this issue. Is it possible cause of the error ?

Comment: why did you mentioned? `lib\\chromedriver.exe` i ever saw something like that in windows.

Comment: Hi @Mona, i just solved the issue by update my ChromeDriver to latest version :)

Thank you very much for your effort helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I need to update the ChromeDrive and replace the previous one.
Under my project directory /lib

Download here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

yes,  i suggest you can mention like this `C:\\Users\\mona\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe`